# Is this application chain rule correct inside the divergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule, divergence-operator

Here $b:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Assume $b$ is nice enough to take enough derivatives.

Is there a neater way of writing this application of chain rule inside the divergence ?
I want to calculate for $T(x)=Ax$ where $A$ is a positive definite matrix
$$ \text{div}_x(b\circ T(x)) $$

I get

$$ \text{div}_x(b\circ T(x))=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\partial_{x_{i}}T_j(x)\partial_{y_j}b_i(y)\Big|_{y=T(x)}=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}T_{j,i}\partial_{y_{j}}b_i(y)\Big|_{y=T(x)}, $$

but can I write this in a neater way using the divergence notation? EDIT : I think I can write the divergence above as Trace$(AJ_b(Ax))$ ?

---

Along the same lines what if $b=D\nabla f$ for some $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$, with $D$ some positive definite square matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{u}=b(\mathbf{y})$ where $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}$.
The differential writes
$$
d\mathbf{u}
= \mathbf{J}_b d\mathbf{y}
= \mathbf{J}_b \mathbf{A} d\mathbf{x}
$$
using the Jacobian matrix.
The divergence simply writes
$
\mathrm{tr}
\left( 
\mathbf{J}_b \mathbf{A}
\right)
$.